# Match URL string on different situations with a single regex

Tags: regex, string, regex-replace

I am trying to match a url in four different situations:

With no attributes

```
<a href="example.com/reviews/audi/a6/">Link without other attr</a>
```

With other attributes

```
<a href="example.com/reviews/audi/a6/" class="button">Link with other attr</a>
```

With no standard href

```
<span data-link="example.com/reviews/audi/a6/">Link with no href</a>
```

Just the URL

```
example.com/reviews/audi/a6
```

In all of them I always want to do the same, swap reviews at the end without an extra `/`

I am using this regex to account for the ones that have another attr by identifing the space after the `"`

```
("example\.com)\/(reviews|used-cars)\/(.*[^\/$])(\/?)(" )
```

But then if it ends in `">` it messes up and matches end of class

```
("example\.com)\/(reviews|used-cars)\/(.*[^\/$])(\/?)(">)
```

https://regex101.com/r/9xbdme/1

Comment: What is the programming language? The regex flavor?

Comment: MariaDB SQL `REGEXP_REPLACE` PCRE I believe

Comment: Aha. Then try `("example\.com)/(reviews|used-cars)/([^"]*[^/"])(/?)(" )` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xbdme/2)).

Comment: But that wont work on links that end on `">` https://regex101.com/r/MEQBwK/1

Comment: `("example\.com)/(reviews|used-cars)/([^"]*[^/"])(/?)("[\s>])` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xbdme/3). In the code, you might have to double escape `\s` (`\\s`).

Comment: No idea, maybe `("?example\.com)/(reviews|used-cars)/([^"\s]*[^/"\s])(/?)("[\s>])?` will do.

Comment: You are not using Group 4, you can remove that group. See https://regex101.com/r/9xbdme/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

*Find*:       `("?example\.com)/(reviews|used-cars)/([^"\s]*[^/"\s])/?("[\s>])?`
*Replace*: `$1/$3/$2/$4`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9xbdme/4).

*Details*:

- `("?example\.com)` - Group 1: an optional `"`, `example.com` string
- `/` - a slash
- `(reviews|used-cars)` - Group 2: `reviews` or `used-cars` string
- `/` - a slash
- `([^"\s]*[^/"\s])` -  Group 3: zero or more chars other than whitespace and `"` (as many as possible) and then a char other than a whitespace, `"` and `/`
- `/?` - an optional slash
- `("[\s>])?` - Group 4 (optional): a `"` and then a `>` or whitespace.

Comment: For MariaDB I had to indeed double escape `\\s` otherwise it splitted words with `s` into two